# Change deepin desktop wallpaper from gsettings

Tags: linux, desktop, desktop-customization

I'm using the Deepin desktop environment on top of Manjaro. I'd like to be able to change the wallpaper every few minutes. I found a gsettings schema? that looked promising: *com.deepin.dde.appearance*, which contains a key by the name of *background-uris*. The key is a list, with the number of entries corresponding to the number of workspaces. I've tried changing the wallpapers with

```
gsettings set com.deepin.dde.appearance background-uris "['file:///path/to/img.png', 'file:///path/to/other.jpg']"
```

but, nothing seems to happen. Does anyone know why this is? Is there a different schema that I should be changing? If not, does anyone know of commands that might be used to change the wallpaper on different workspaces in Deepin every few minutes?

Comment: Has the same problem, the wallpaper is changed but I have to wait for a reboot to see it displayed. Did you find the answer ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found an answer @BDeliers.

Answer (score 1):

I use another schema with dconf that works

```
dconf write /com/deepin/wrap/gnome/desktop/background/picture-uri "'/path/to/image'"
```

You can alternatively use this one

```
gsettings set com.deepin.wrap.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri /path/to/image
```